# Grunt: copying files very slow. How to improve performance?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

I've inherited application code that uses **Grunt** (1.0.0) to build its AngularJS front-end.

What suprised me is that build action step 'copy' (implemented with [grunt-contrib-copy plugin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy/)) takes very long time: more than 1 minute, while I would expect it to take less than a second.

Here are the [execution time statistics](https://github.com/sindresorhus/time-grunt) for `grunt build`, including problematic `copy` tasks:

```
 loading tasks             1.4s  - 2%
 uglify:build             14.4s  ---------- 16%
 copy:common            1m 6.4s  ---------------------------------------- 76%
 copy:partner_xxxxx        4.9s  --- 6%

 Total 1m 27.9s
```

The number of copied files seems reasonable:

```
 Running "copy:common" (copy) task
 Created 12 directories, copied 179 files
```

Copying this same destination folder in Windows Explorer takes less than 1 second (drive is a fast SSD).

Here's how gulp task is defined:

```
copy: {
  common: {
    cwd: '.',
    src: [
      '**/*.html',
      '**/*.json',
      '**/*.cur',
      '**/partials/**/*.js',
      '**/directives/**/*.js',
      '**/app-services/**/*.js',
      '**/main-scripts/**/*.js',
      '**/bundles/**',
      '**/images/**',
      '**/utils/**',
      '!**/tests/**',
      '!**/partner-info/**',
      '!**/bower_components/**',
      '!**/node_modules/**',
      '!bower.json',
      '!package.json'
    ],
    dest: publishDest+ "//<%= grunt.option('partnerName') %>"
  },
  expand: true
}
```

My question is: is it normal for Grunt to be this slow? Are there any gotchas that may slow down this process? **Do you see any ways to improve this time**?

Comment: Gulp uses streams/pipelines and can run tasks in parallel, as opposed to Grunt's temp files and (typically) single-tasking: https://www.keycdn.com/blog/gulp-vs-grunt/ That said, you might want to consider simple npm scripts: https://medium.freecodecamp.com/why-i-left-gulp-and-grunt-for-npm-scripts-3d6853dd22b8

Comment: Grunt is not intended to be efficient in this manner, thus you might want to switch to Gulp if that's your bottleneck. However, you can also try to use a tool like [`newer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-newer) to make the entire process more efficient.

Comment: @TrueWill: thanks for the interesting reads. I'll take it into consideration when I'm in position to choose a tool :)

Comment: @jakerella: thanks for your ideas! Unfortunately 'newer' didn't change execution time (other people tried it too: https://github.com/giovannipds/grunt-newer-copy-test)

Comment: Dang... that sucks, why are ALL those files being changed then? Seems like not all of them should have. Does a re-run of grunt immediately after a first run go faster?

Comment: @jakerella Subsequent runs are no faster. I guess those plugins are not compatible in some way, but I didn't dig too deep into it ;)

Comment: Please use operating system's cp/copy commands to copy files. Not javascript.